# What languages installed with APT on Ubuntu come with graphical features straight out of the box?

Tags: apt, python, gcc, programming, c

Just wondering what programming languages I can install straight from the APT that come with built in graphics functions on Ubuntu. I know Java can but I don't know of anything else and information on this is a bit scarce. Can C in GCC produce graphics? Python? Fortran? As far as I know this requires interfacing with APIs which from what I can gather are designed to easily interact with the languages, but I'm not sure.

I am interested in creating games and simulations, and maybe experimenting with Doom style 3d graphics eventually.

Does anyone have more information on this topic? If it's capable of producing graphics at all without modification that's enough for me, but features that simplify this are definitely desirable.

Comment: C in Ubuntu can generate graphics, and there are libraries that are pre-installed that can do that, but to build your own, you'd need the development headers, which are not pre-installed.

Comment: @muru Do you know the names of these libraries? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily produce graphics with Python.

If you want to create graphs for scientific computing, check out matplotlib.

```
sudo apt install python3-matplotlib
```

To create graphical apps with python, many options are available, including tkinter, pyqt5, and many more.

Check out [pysimplegui](https://realpython.com/pysimplegui-python/), which combines some of these. It can be installed with

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user pysimplegui --break-system-packages
```

(note that the last command installs pysimplegui as a user package, and really cannot break any system packages in this case)

Another way to install pysimplegui is to install pipx with `sudo apt install pipx` and then install pysimplegui with `pipx install pysimplegui` (You don't need `sudo`). Then run `psghome` to launch PySimpleGUI 5.

The combination of Spyder 5 and Python is capable of producing inline graphics.

---

If you want to develop games, then using a Game Engine would be a convenient option. Check out [Linux game development on Ubuntu: Godot and Unity](https://ubuntu.com/blog/get-started-with-linux-game-development-on-ubuntu), a blog post by Ubuntu developers

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am interested in creating games and simulations and maybe experimenting with doom style 3d graphics eventually. Do you think any compiled languages would be capable of this, like C?

Comment: I am sure there are gaming libraries for C, but I don't have any experience with them. I updated my answer with gaming engines

Comment: Alright, so I tried entering this:

sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user pysimplegui

But it gave me an error, saying "eternally-managed-environment" and it gave me a warning about installing non-debian based packages.

Comment: Another way to install pysimplegui is to install pipx with `sudo apt install pipx`  and then install pysimplegui with `pipx install pysimplegui` (You don't need `sudo`).  Then run `psghome` to launch PySimpleGUI 5.

Comment: @karel Feel free to edit my answer with that information

Comment: @LonelyLad I updated the command in my answer

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you so much! Looks like it installed! I suppose to use it in python I'd write "import pysimplegui"?

Comment: @LonelyLad Here is how to use it https://realpython.com/pysimplegui-python/#creating-basic-ui-elements-in-pysimplegui